# Bluetooth module for BNEP

Tags: bluetooth

I would like to ask you, local experts, for a suggestion. I want to implement a Bluetooth PANU device, which will be connectable with a cell phone in PANU-PANU mode. For that, I neeed to implement BNEP profile on top of L2CAP. And here is the problem. I have not been able to find any bluetooth module with a stack that supports defining the Class of Device and service record for PANU. I have checked out the following modules:

- **PAN1322 Series USB Starter Kit** based on PAN1322 and *eUniStone* stack. This one supports defining the advertising data, but it seems like the profiles have to be based on SPP profile only. No other profiles is supported.
- **nBlue™ BR-EVAL-LE4.0-S2A** based on PAN1720 and *BlueRadios*. This one seems to support only some proprietary BRSP protocol for Serial Line emulation. Although it supports editing the advertising data, this capability is very limited and does not allow me to specify the service record for BNEP. Also I don't know if it even works this way, because the documentation is unclear to me.
- **BLE113** with  *Bluegiga Bluetooth Smart Stack*. This one is quite nicely configurable for BT Smart profiles using GATT services definitions, but I see no way how to define a new profile on top of the L2CAP.
- **WT12* with *iWrap* stack. It supports 13 BT profiles, but BNEP is not one of them and I also lack a way how to implement it.

I am quite new to Bluetooth technology so please correct me if I am totally wrong in something. Please if somebody knows a module or stack that has implemented BNEP or at least L2CAP and Advertising database available for developer, let me know. And most of all, is my assumption that I need access to L2CAP layer/profile/protocol, whatever it is, to implement the BNEP and PANU on top of it?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions and corrections.

Comment: Linux bluez? Bluez supported profiles listed [here](http://www.bluez.org/profiles/). It supports PAN in PANU, NAP and GN roles.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't think Bluez is an option as we have no operating system on the application microcontroller. There will be RTOS in the future.

Comment: OK, I have contacted several others Bluetooth module providers and I have found out that none of them provides access to the L2CAP via AT commands. However I have confirmed that the BNEP protocol can be implemented just by sending packets directly via L2CAP protocol. Another new information is, that BNEP is supported only by Bluetooth classic. For BLE there will be 6LoPAN profile in the future. So the module would have to be dual mode. And finally I have found that there is a possibility to communicate with some Bluetooth controllers via HCI. I am doing research about this right now.

Comment: So it seems like there is no other option but to implement my own stack (probably based on smalltooth) on HCI interface.